# How to get the active user username using 'query user'

Tags: powershell, scripting

I will be running a script on a users box that does some work on a remote server. However, the user will not have access to the server, so I will be running the script as a different user with permissions.

The bit that I'm having difficulty with is that I need to grab the logged on user's (the box user) username and domain to pass to the server. There are various commands that can grab the data I need, but when running PowerShell ISE as a different user, they all return that users data not the logged on users data.

Some of the commands I am speaking of:

```bsh
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```

```bsh
$env:USERNAME
$env:USERDOMAIN
```

```bsh
$(whoami)
```

The only one that seems to work the way I want it to is:

```bsh
query user
```

This returns the format of:

```
USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>user1                sessionName         4  Active          .  6/22/2017 2:56 PM
```

My two questions are:

1. Is there a way to get the domain in this way too? I dont see it when I run this command.
2. Is there a way to just grab the username out of query user? what about specificity the 'active' username?

Comment: What's the issue with using `$env:USERNAME` and `$env:USERDOMAIN`?

Comment: My guess is that he's trying to determine the user/domain of a user in another session.

Comment: @thepip3r Hmmm... from the question I understand that there are 2 users. But to me it seems a bit backwards to get the remote (server) session to query the information of the local (box) user; it would make more sense to use the built-in environment variables, and pass them to the remotely executing code - as script or function parameters... (disclaimer: I haven't messed around much with remoting so could be missing something)

Comment: I don't understand what he's trying to do either but this was the most compelling piece for me, "I will be running the script as a different user with permissions".  meaning, the user will be in a different session than the script (and possibly on another computer).  Could be wrong but that was my interpretation.

Comment: @gms0ulman the issue with that is it returns the info for the user running the powershell session and not the logged in user

Comment: also to clarify a bit: I will be using a service account to write a file to a server from the users box. so the script will run from the users box but the service account will be the one running it from the users box, and I need to write the users data to the file being written. And the user will not have access to the server but the service account will, which is why its being used in the first place

Comment: @Zirono Thanks, with the additional info the question makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query active user:

```
query user | Select-String '^>(\w+)' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
```

This depends on usernames not containing whitespace. Add the `/server` parameter to the `query` command to query a remote computer.

Comment: Thank you @Bill_Stewart, this is what I was looking for to extract the username.

Comment: @Zirono - sounds good - feel free to mark an answer if you consider your question as answered.

Comment: Any idea how `query user` determines the state of a user? Is it also via   `explorer.exe`?

Answer (score 2):

win32_loggedonuser has all of the information you need in the 'antecedent' property for each user.  You'll need to filter it using string-parsing but it has what you're looking for.  if you want any additional, session-related information, you can use the value in the 'dependent' property to search Win32_logonsession for things like logontype and starttime.

```
$s = (gwmi win32_loggedonuser).antecedent.split('=')
$s[1].Replace('"', '').Replace(',Name', '') ## domain
$s[2].Replace('"','') ## username
```

edit:  the above displays parsing the output in a single user scenario.  in a multi-user scenario, you'd need to loop through the results and perform like-operations for each user.  my intent was to provide an example.

edit2:  the -computername property on Get-WmiObject will allow you to run this against remote computers--with the appropriate permissions of course.

Comment: Thanks @thepip3r, I think I can use this in a loop like you suggested in combination with Bill_Stewart's answer to get exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You could enumerate the logged-in desktop users via WMI and filter that list by the username you extracted from the `query user` output (see [Bill_Stewart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44784598/1630171)):

```
$user = (& query user) -replace '^>(\S+).*', '$1'

$qry = 'SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name="explorer.exe"'
Get-WmiObject -Query $qry | ForEach-Object {
    $_.GetOwner()
} | Sort-Object -Unique User, Domain | Where-Object {
    $_.User -eq $user
} | ForEach-Object {
    '{0}\{1}' -f $_.Domain, $_.User
}
```

The `query user` command lists remote desktop sessions/users, so you'll need to filter the output of the command if more than one user can be logged in at the same time.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I thought of too and then I reloaded the page and saw youre answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to grep by SESSIONNAME:

```
$userInfo =  (cmd /c "query user") | Out-String -Stream
For ($i = 0; $i -le $userInfo.Count; $i++)

{
If ($($userInfo[$i]) -like "*console*")
{
    $consoleUser = (($($userInfo[$i]) -Split ">")[1] -Split " ")[0]
    Break
}
}
```